# Find the longest run of sequential integers in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a routine that returns a list of integers as a vector.

Those integers come from groups of sequential numbers; for example, it may look like this:

```
vector = 6 7 8 12 13 14 15 26 27 28 29 30 55 56
```

Note that above, there are four 'runs' of numbers (6-8, 12-15, 26-30 & 55-56). What I'd like to do is forward the *longest* 'run' of numbers to a new vector. In this case, that would be the 26-30 run, so I'd like to produce:

```
newVector = 26 27 28 29 30
```

This calculation has to be performed many, many times on various vectors, so the more efficiently I can do this the better! Any wisdom would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try this:

```
v = [ 6 7 8 12 13 14 15 26 27 28 29 30 55 56];

x = [0 cumsum(diff(v)~=1)];

v(x==mode(x))
```

This results in

```
ans =

    26    27    28    29    30
```

Comment: I think I just had a nerdgasm

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to get the ball rolling . . .

```
vector = [6 7 8 12 13 14 15 26 27 28 29 30 55 56]
d = [diff(vector) 0]


maxSequence = 0;
maxSequenceIdx = 0;
lastIdx = 1;

while lastIdx~=find(d~=1, 1, 'last')

    idx = find(d~=1, 1);
    if idx-lastIdx > maxSequence
        maxSequence = idx-lastIdx;
        maxSequenceIdx = lastIdx;
    end

    d(idx) = 1;

    lastIdx=idx;
end

output = vector(1+maxSequenceIdx:maxSequenceIdx+maxSequence)
```

In this example, the diff command is used to find consecutive numbers. When numbers are consecutive, the difference is 1. A while loop is then used to find the longest group of ones, and the index of this consecutive group is stored. However, I'm confident that this could be optimised further.

Answer (score 1):

Without loops - should be faster

```
temp = find ( ([(vector(2:end) - vector(1:end-1))==1 0])==0);
[len,ind]=max(temp(2:end)-temp(1:end-1));
vec_out =  vector(temp(ind)+1:temp(ind)+len)
```

Comment: You have a mistake. It fails for `vector = [1 3 4 5];`

Comment: Thanks, it failed when the sequence was in the end of the vector. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Without loops using `diff`:

```
vector = [6 7 8 12 13 14 15 26 27 28 29 30 55 56];

seqGroups = [1 find([1 diff(vector)]~=1) numel(vector)+1]; % beginning of group
[~, groupIdx] = max( diff(seqGroups));                     % bigger group index

output = vector( seqGroups(groupIdx):seqGroups(groupIdx+1)-1)
```

output vector is

```
ans = 

    26    27    28    29    30
```